# Rails 3 - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I migrated a Rails 2.2.2 site over to Rails 3.1. The schema is identical but now I get an ActiveRecord error when the model calls save() on a partial INSERT.

This is causing a constraint issue, which really isn't because the column is auto-incrementing in PostGres, thus it will never be NULL.

Rails is all conventions and I thought it assumes 'id' column to be the primary key.

What's the best way to handle this?

**1)** Remove the "NOT NULL" from the schema column definition

**2)** Some way from inside Rails 3 to tell ActiveRecord.save() to ignore this constraint since it's an auto-increment field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model do this:

```
self.primary_key = "your PK column name"
```

Comment: Not the best approach because you are now messing with your schema integrity